# How to resolve - ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value in Python

Tags: python, pandas, google-natural-language, google-cloud-language

I have some sample code that I use to analyze entities and its sentiments using Google's natural language API. For every record in my Pandas dataframe, I want to return a list of dictionaries where each element is an entity. However, I am running into issues when trying to have it work on the production data. Here is the sample code

```
from google.cloud import language_v1 # version 2.0.0
import os 
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'path/to/json'
import pandas as pd 

# establish client connection
client = language_v1.LanguageServiceClient()

# helper function 
def custom_analyze_entity(text_content):
    global client
    #print("Accepted Input::" + text_content)
    document = language_v1.Document(content=text_content, type_=language_v1.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT, language = 'en')
    response = client.analyze_entity_sentiment(request = {'document': document})
    # a document can have many entities
    # create a list of dictionaries, every element in the list is a dictionary that represents an entity
    # the dictionary is nested
    l = []
    #print("Entity response:" + str(response.entities))
    for entity in response.entities:
        #print('=' * 20)
        temp_dict = {}
        temp_meta_dict = {}
        temp_mentions = {}
        temp_dict['name'] = entity.name
        temp_dict['type'] = language_v1.Entity.Type(entity.type_).name
        temp_dict['salience'] = str(entity.salience)
        sentiment = entity.sentiment
        temp_dict['sentiment_score'] = str(sentiment.score)
        temp_dict['sentiment_magnitude'] = str(sentiment.magnitude)
        for metadata_name, metadata_value in entity.metadata.items():
            temp_meta_dict['metadata_name'] = metadata_name
            temp_meta_dict['metadata_value'] = metadata_value
        temp_dict['metadata'] = temp_meta_dict
        for mention in entity.mentions:
            temp_mentions['mention_text'] = str(mention.text.content)
            temp_mentions['mention_type'] = str(language_v1.EntityMention.Type(mention.type_).name)
        temp_dict['mentions'] = temp_mentions
        #print(u"Appended Entity::: {}".format(temp_dict))
        l.append(temp_dict)
    return l
```

I have tested it on sample data and it works fine

```
# works on sample data 
data= ['Grapes are good. Bananas are bad.', 'the weather is not good today', 'Michelangelo Caravaggio, Italian painter, is known for many arts','look i cannot articulate how i feel today but its amazing to be back on the field with runs under my belt.']
input_df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns = ['freeform_text'])

for i in range(len(input_df)):
    op = custom_analyze_entity(input_df.loc[i,'freeform_text'])
    input_df.loc[i, 'entity_object'] = op
```

But when i try to parse it thru production data using below code, it fails with multi-index error. I am not able to reproduce the error using the sample pandas dataframe.

```
for i in range(len(input_df)):
    op = custom_analyze_entity(input_df.loc[i,'freeform_text'])
    input_df.loc[i, 'entity_object'] = op
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 670, in __setitem__
    iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1667, in _setitem_with_indexer
    "cannot set using a multi-index "
ValueError: cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
input_df.loc[0, 'entity_object'] = ""
for i in range(len(input_df)):
    op = custom_analyze_entity(input_df.loc[i,'freeform_text'])
    input_df.loc[i, 'entity_object'] = op
```

Or for your specific case, you don't need to use the **loc** function.

```
input_df["entity_object"] = ""
    for i in range(len(input_df)):
        op = custom_analyze_entity(input_df.loc[i,'freeform_text'])     
        input_df["entity_object"][i] = op
```